# Inheritance in SuperClass and SubClasses using c++ giving error

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, subclass, superclass

I am working on an Banking project in C++

When compiling, its giving me an error

`C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\FinanceApp\account.cpp:5: error: redefinition of 'Account::Account(QString, QString, double, QString)'
 Account::Account(QString cn, QString an, double ir, QString ty)
 ^`

Below are my files

## SuperClass

### account.h

```
#ifndef ACCOUNT_H
#define ACCOUNT_H
#include <QString>
#include <QList>
#include <transaction.h>


class Account
{
public:
    Account(QString cn, QString an, double ir, QString ty) : custName(cn), accNum(an), interestRate(ir), type(ty){}
    virtual ~Account();
    QString getCustName();
    QString getAccNum();
    QList<Transaction> getTransaction();
    virtual QString toString();
    QString getType();
    void setType(QString ty);
    double getInterestRate() const;
    virtual void transaction(double amt) = 0;
    virtual void calcInterest() = 0;
    void getAccountInfo();

protected:
    double balance;
    QList<Transaction> transactions;
private:
    QString custName;
    QString accNum;
    double interestRate;
    QString type;
};

#endif // ACCOUNT_H
```

### account.cpp

```
#include "account.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

Account::Account(QString cn, QString an, double ir, QString ty)
{
}

QString Account::toString(){

    QString accountString;
    accountString += "ACCOUNT DETAILS";
    accountString += "---------------";
    accountString += "\n\tAccount No    : " + accNum;
    accountString += "\n\tAccount holder: " + custName;
    accountString += "\n\tBalance       : " + QString::number(balance,'f',2);
    accountString += "\n\n\tTransactions";
    accountString += "\n\n\t------------";

    foreach(Transaction single_transact, this->transactions)
    {
        accountString += "\n\t\t" + single_transact.toString();
    }

    return accountString;
}

QString Account::getCustName(){
    return this->custName;
}

QString Account::getAccNum(){
    return this->accNum;
}

QList<Transaction> Account::getTransaction(){
    return this->transactions;
}

QString Account::getType(){
    return this->type;
}

void Account::setType(QString ty){
    this->type = ty;
}

double Account::getInterestRate()const{
    return this->interestRate;
}

void Account::getAccountInfo(){

    std::string cn, an, ty;


        std::cout<< "\n\nEnter Customer Name :- ";
        std::cin>> cn;
        std::cout<< "Enter Account Number :- ";
        std::cin>> an;
        std::cout<< "Enter Account Type :- ";
        std::cin>> ty;

        this->custName = QString::fromStdString(cn);
        this->accNum = QString::fromStdString(an);
        this->type = QString::fromStdString(ty);

}
```

## Subclass

### savingsaccount.h

```
#ifndef SAVINGSACCOUNT_H
#define SAVINGSACCOUNT_H
#include <QString>
#include "account.h"

class SavingsAccount : public Account
{
public:
    SavingsAccount();
    SavingsAccount(QString cn, QString an, double ir, QString ty);
    double minIntEarnedForPoints;
    void transaction(double amt);
    void calcInterest();
    int getPoints();
    QString toString();
    void make_withdrawal();
    void make_deposit();
    void print_statement();
    void print_balance();
    void print_account_type();
    void print_points_earned();
private:
    int points;
};

#endif // SAVINGSACCOUNT_H
```

### savingsaccount.cpp

```
#include "savingsaccount.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QList>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(QString cn, QString an, double ir, QString ty):{
    this->custName = cn;
    this->accNum = an;
    this->interestRate = ir;
    this->type = ty;
}

void SavingsAccount::transaction(double amt){

    QString transaction_type;

    this->setType("Savings");

    if(amt < 0){
        transaction_type = "Withdrawal";
    }else{
        transaction_type = "Deposit";
    }

    if(this->balance >= amt){

        this->balance += amt;

        Transaction _t = Transaction(transaction_type, amt);

        this->transactions::append(_t);

        std::cout << "Transaction successful.\n";

        std::cout << this->toString() + "\n" + transaction_type + "\t:\t" + amt;

    }else{
        std::cout << "Insufficient funds.";
    }

}

void SavingsAccount::calcInterest(){

    QString transaction_type = "Interest";

    double new_interest = this->balance * (this->getInterestRate()/100) * (1/12);

    this->balance += new_interest;

    int points_earned = 0;

    if(new_interest > this->minIntEarnedForPoints){
        points_earned = (int)new_interest;
    }
    this->points += points_earned;
    Account::transactions.append(new Transaction(transaction_type, new_interest));

    std::cout << "Transaction successful.\n";

    std::cout << this->toString() + "\n" + "Interest" + "\t:\t" + new_interest;

    std::cout << "\nPoints \t:\t"+QString::number(points_earned);

}

void SavingsAccount::print_points_earned(){

    std::cout << "Points Earned: " << this->points;

}

void SavingsAccount::getPoints(){

    return this->points;

}

QString SavingsAccount::toString(){

    QString savings_account = "SAVINGS ACCOUNT\n";
    savings_account += "------------------------------";
    savings_account += Account::toString();
    savings_account += "\nMinimum Earned Points: " + QString::number(this->getPoints(),'f',2);
    savings_account += "\n\n";
    return savings_account;

}

void SavingsAccount::make_withdrawal(){
    double amt;
    std::cout <<"\nEnter amount to Withdraw :- ";
    std::cin>>amt;
    double amount = 0-amt;
    transaction(amount);
}

void SavingsAccount::make_deposit(){
    double amt;
    std::cout <<"\nEnter amount to Deposit :- ";
    std::cin>>amt;
    transaction(amt);
}

void SavingsAccount::print_statement(){

    std::cout << "Statement";
    std::cout << "---------";

    foreach(Transaction single_transact, this->transactions)
    {
        std::cout << single_transact.toString();
    }
}

void SavingsAccount::print_balance(){

    std::cout << "ChequeAccount Balance: " << this->balance;

}

void SavingsAccount::print_account_type(){

    std::cout << this->toString();
}
```

*I need help on how to properly structure the SubClass using a SuperClass*
Im stuck with the error highlighted above. It is also showing another error

`C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\FinanceApp\account.h:11: error: 'Account::Account(QString, QString, double, QString)' previously defined here
     Account(QString cn, QString an, double ir, QString ty) : custName(cn), accNum(an), interestRate(ir), type(ty){}
     ^`

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You defined your `Account::Account` constructor in the header file.

And then you defined it again in `account.cpp`, which includes the header file. That's your duplicate definition.

Either only declare the constructor in the header file; or leave the definition there, and remove it from `account.cpp`.

Comment: So what would be a clean and minimum way of defining the Subclass in both the header .h and the .cpp

Comment: This has nothing to do with defining the subclass, but defining the constructor in the superclass. The subclass has absolutely nothing to do with this, whatsoever. Delete everything that references the subclass. You'll still get the same compilation error.